# Could two concatenated cycloids be an optimal solution to the Brachistochrone problem?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, variational-principle, optimization, brachistochrone-problem

The following is a specific instance of the brachistochrone
problem, which I first encountered in grad school, and I
have occasionally used as hw problem in teaching CM.

> A particle is started from rest at the origin and constrained to fall under gravity along a path $y(x)$ which passes through the point $x=5$, $y=-1$ (in arbitrary units, for example meters). We will assume that the gravitational
> potential is linear, $V=mgz$.
> a) Determine the path that minimizes the time taken. Make a plot of that path. 
> b) Is there another path that makes the time taken stationary? If yes, make
> a plot of that path and explain whether this path is a minimum, a
> maximum, or a saddle point.

The solution to the brachistochrone problem is of course very well known, so this assignment is really about finding a specific cycloid that satisfies the boundary conditions. As part b indicates, there is more than one: The standard cycloid, and two cycloids that ``bounce''.

[image]

Now it is clear that the simple cycloid is the absolute minimum, because traversal time is proportional to the angle traced out. But
what about the other two? Naively they should be saddles, but the second variation of the action functional is manifestly positive, indicating that they are local minima. But that can't be right, unless there is something funny about the topology of the space of paths. Are the higher cycloids saddle points or minima?

P.S.: To see that the higher cycloids cannot easily be dismissed as solutions, consider this plot of the velocity components $(v_x,v_y)$ as a function of time for the second cycloid.

[image]

The corresponding components of the acceleration are:

[image]

Clearly, the acceleration (and the forces of constraint) are perfectly smooth.

Comment: There are many paths for which the traversal time is infinite (or maybe negative), right? I think there should be no local maxima, only singularities.

Comment: @Daniel Yes, there are obviously arbitrarily shallow, infinite time, path. However, it would seem to me that you can continuously deform one of the cycloids into the others without encountering an infinite time path

Comment: Good point. A different thought: Isn't traversal time undefined for the two solutions that bounce? See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norton%27s_dome

Comment: @Daniel In principle the bounce solutions seem fine -- finite travel time (clear from t-symmetry), continuous forces, etc. However, in terms of the variational problem these paths are indeed singular. There is an infinitesimal $\delta z(x)$ that makes the travel time infinite.

Comment: I agree that there exist finite-travel-time solutions, but I don't agree that these are solutions are unique. Along the path, force is proportional to $\frac{dy}{dx}$. This derivative is undefined at a cusp, so the force is also undefined at a cusp. Usually this doesn't matter, since it's only one point, but the particle also arrives at the cusp with zero velocity. It seems reasonable to define the force at the cusp to be zero. Then a consistent (but not unique!) solution to Newton's laws is a particle that rolls up to the cusp, stops, and sits there forever.

Comment: @Daniel note that force is $(\ddot x,\ddot y)$, which is perfectly well behaved (because $d\theta\sim dt$ along the cycloid). Also note that even if there is some criterion (say, second variational derivative well defined) that can be used to exclude the bounce cycloid, we can still construct a series of trajectories in which the cusp is smoothed out, and the travel time is arbitrarily close to the cuspy cycloid.

Comment: We both agree that the force is the component of gravity tangential to the path, right? (I should have said "a function of $\frac{dx}{dy}$", not "proportional to.")

Regarding your other point: I think there exist sequences of smooth trajectories approaching the "bounce" cycloid for which the travel time approaches infinity (but remains finite everywhere on the sequence).

Comment: @Daniel Added a plot to show what the forces look like.

Comment: Good point, the alternative trajectories I'm envisioning do have discontinuous acceleration. If we restrict ourselves to paths for which acceleration is continuous, I think we get a well-defined traversal time. Next question: If $f_0$ and $f_1$ describe the first and second cycloids, could you plot traversal time for $af_0 + (1 - a)f_1, a \in [0,1]$? Or do intermediate paths not have solutions with continuous accelerations?

Comment: @Daniel These paths are singular (I would expect), so there is at least on direction in configuration space along which the first and second cycloid are separated by an infinite barrier.

Comment: I agree that there exist paths from $f_1$ to $f_2$ where travel time diverges somewhere along the path, but I don't think the path I described is one of them. The problem with the path I described is that there are no solutions with continuous acceleration. But I think we're most of the way to an answer now. The paths in a neighborhood of the "bounce" cycloid seem to either have arbitrary long travel times, or not admit solutions with continuous acceleration (so that we can't choose a unique solution). Any ideas as to how we prove this?

Comment: @Daniel I found a textbook (Blachard, Bruning, Variational Methods) that claims that the traversal time functional of the Brachistochrone is a convex functional on the space of paths (p.114). Personally, I don't see how that can be true, but it's a little hard to check because we only have the paths in parametric form.

Comment: Does it specify which space of paths? The functional is not even defined on every path, I think. The claim seems plausible for the space of smooth paths with finite, uniquely-defined traversal times.
Also, I think my previous comment can be made more specific: There is no way to deform a path with a cusp on the x-axis into a path with no cusp on the x-axis without passing through a path where travel time is undefined.

Comment: They seem to assume that it is a Banach space, so maybe we need to show that the cycloid is the limit of a sequence of differentiable paths, which would bring us back to the problem of constructing a suitable sequence. I actually tried to regularize by complexifying $x,y=Re[(x(\theta+I\epsilon),y(\theta+I\epsilon))]$. This is a strange path (it deforms the cusp to a loop), but looks differentiable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

TL;DR: A path built piecewise from more than 1 [cycloid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycloid) (each with possibly different energy $E$, see below), and with cusps at the $x$-axis, is not stationary.

*Sketched proof:*

1. Recall that the action (=spent time) of the [brachistochrone problem](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/BrachistochroneProblem.html) is
   $$S~=~\int_0^a\! \mathrm{d}x~L,\qquad  L~=~\sqrt{\frac{1+y^{\prime 2}}{y}},\qquad y~\geq~ 0,\tag{1}$$
   with boundary conditions $y(0)=0$ and $y(a)=b$. (Here the $y$-axis is pointing downwards and we chose for simplicity units of time and space such that $2g=1$.)
2. Physically, we demand that the path $x\mapsto y(x)$ is at least continuous. Mathematically, the integrand should just be Lebesgue integrable. To be as simple as possible but also incorporate OP's examples we will strike a convenient compromise and assume that the path $x\mapsto y(x)$ is [piecewise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piecewise) continuously differentiable, although we will allow the derivative $y^{\prime}\equiv \frac{dy}{dx}$ to become singular at the points between the pieces as long as the integrand remains Lebesgue integrable.
3. It follows that a stationary path necessarily satisfies [Euler-Lagrange (EL) equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Lagrange_equation) within the interior of each piece. Additional conditions may arise at the points between the pieces.
4. Since the Lagrangian $L$ has no explicit $x$-dependence the corresponding notion of energy (within a piece) is conserved:
   $$E~=~ y^{\prime} \frac{\partial L}{\partial y^{\prime}}-L~\stackrel{(1)}{=}~-\frac{1}{\sqrt{y(1+y^{\prime 2})}}~<~0.\tag{2}$$
5. The piece solution is a cycloid:
   $$\begin{align} 2E^2x~=~&\theta-\sin\theta~\approx~\frac{\theta^3}{6},\cr 
   2E^2y~=~&1-\cos\theta~\approx~\frac{\theta^2}{2},\end{align}\tag{3}$$
   where the approximation is valid close to the cusp. The cusp-equation becomes
   $$ y~\stackrel{(3)}{\propto}~ x^{2/3}.\tag{4}$$
   Near the cusp, the particle is performing a free falling motion, which is smooth as a function of time $t$.
6. The idea is now to truncate the cusp at some horizontal the level $y=\epsilon\ll 1$, i.e. at some $x~\propto~ y^{3/2}~=~\epsilon^{3/2}$. (We consider for simplicity just the right branch of the cusp -- the left branch is similar.) The action of the cusp is
   $$L~\stackrel{(1)+(2)}{=}~\frac{1}{|E|y}~\stackrel{(4)}{\propto}~ x^{-2/3}\qquad\Rightarrow\qquad S~\propto~x^{1/3} ~\propto~\epsilon^{1/2}.\tag{5}$$
   For comparison, the action of the horizontal path is as expected faster:
   $$L~\stackrel{(1)}{=}~\frac{1}{\sqrt{y}}~=~ \frac{1}{\sqrt{\epsilon}}\qquad\Rightarrow\qquad S~\propto~\frac{x}{\sqrt{\epsilon}} ~\stackrel{(4)}{\propto}~\epsilon.\tag{6}$$
   This shows that we can change the action to first order in $\epsilon$, and hence the path is not stationary. $\Box$

Comment: Thanks, that's a very nice observation. Two quick questions: 1) If there is a term of order $\sqrt{\epsilon}$, does that not imply that the variational derivative $\delta S/\delta x$ is ill defined (infinite)? 2) Am I allowed to use $E=const$ in carrying out the variation ($E=const$ only for stationary paths)?

Comment: 1) It is certainly not a stationary path. 2) $E=const$ is true for cycloid segments, but not for generic paths.