# Non-differentiable solution of the Brachistochrone problem

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, mathematics, variational-principle, brachistochrone-problem

Is there a solution to the brachistochrone problem where the solution is non-differentiable everywhere (angular point)?
The Euler-Lagrange method fails if the first or second derivative of the solution do not exist.

Comment: Related : **(1)**  [What is the position as a function of time for a mass falling down a cycloid curve?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/177847/). **(2)** [Another Solution To Brachistochrone Problem](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/594706/). **(3)** [Brachistochrone to a vertical line](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/656249/).

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/574337/2451